# regex for removing characters at end of string

Tags: c#, regex

i would like to match recursively, all text that ends with  `:` or `/` or `;` or `,` and remove all these characters, along with any spaces left behind, in the end of the text.

Example:

```
some text :  ;  ,    /
```

should become:

```
some text
```

What i have tried, just removes the first occurrence of any of these special characters found, how one can do this recursively, so as to delete all characters 
found that match?
regex i use:

find:   `[ ,;:/]*`

replace with nothing

Comment: So you know this can be solved with the help of regular expression, what have you tried to find those characters and to remove them? Please share your code.

Comment: *What i have tried, just removes the first occurrence of any of these special characters found*  - please post that pattern and the code behind to see what *problem* you have.

Comment: The regex you said you use doesn't have one of the characters you want to remove... is this your problem or is that a typo?

Comment: What about the space between "text" and ":" ? Should it be removed?

Comment: yes, the spaces need to be removed also, and yes, it was a typo in my regex, i need to make a recursive replacement, so that in one pass, all the characters in the regex should be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[ ,;:/]*$` should be what you need. This is the same as your current regex except with the `$` on the end. The `$` tells it that the match must happen at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use C#'s `TrimEnd()` like so

```
string line = "some text :  ;  ,    / " 
char[] charsToTrim = {',', ':', ';', ' ', '/'};
string trimmedLine = line.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
```

Comment: i am looking for a regex, solution, i know which function to use, thank you